# Cannot find declaration to go to after targeting SDK 33

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

After updating the `targetSdk` and `compileSdk` from 31 to 33, I cannot go to declarations from XML layout files, from example to strings.

> Cannot find declaration to go to

Invalidate cache restart and delete `.idea` `.gradle` don't work.

It not only does not go to declarations, but also the autocompile does not work when I type the string name.

Comment: The same issue here. Updated to compileSdk 33 as it's required for version 1.9.0 of androidx.core:core-ktx dependency. As soon as I changed compileSdk to 33, the declaration couldn't be found. Solved it by rolling back to the previous version of the dependency and continued using compileSdk 32.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same error, and I downloaded files from Android with the newest.

[Android Studio Dolphin](https://developer.android.com/studio/archive) (2021.3.1) RC1.

With `com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.2`.

```
https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.5.1-bin.zip
```

Comment: Why the backslash before "`:`" (colon)?

Comment: It's android studio autowritten line when we import new version of gradle. You can consider that `.properties`  file find this as link